# How to add Angular routing for three distict views

Tags: angular, angular-router

We are migrating an AngularJS 1.8 application to Angular 13 and I'm unable to find any hints on how to create three distinct views using Angular routing. The views are:

- main
- monitoring
- onboarding

Each view has a distinctive layout where information is shown within a single `router-outlet`. The `app-component.html` just contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and I want to place each view inside this outlet.

I have the following routes defined:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'mainsub', component: MainSubComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'onboarding',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: OnboardingComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'onboardingsub', component: OnboardingSubComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'monitor',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: MonitorComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'monitorsub', component: MonitorSubComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

In the `MainComponent` I want to navigate to the first child:

```
constructor(private router:Router, private route:activatedRoute) {};

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.navigate(['mainsub'], {relativeTo:this.route});
}
```

However, this fails as the route `mainsub` is unknown.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed a lot ;)

Upon more searching online I found [this](https://dev.to/raj_sekhar/angular-route-pathmatch-full-when-to-not-use-4mb1) article about the uses of `pathMatch`. In short I needed to use the following routes (for the main view):

```
const routes = [
{
  path: '', pathMatch: 'prefix', component: MainComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'mainsub' },
    { path: 'mainsub', component: MainSubComponent }
  ]
};
```

This also removes the need to add the router redirect in the `MainComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with firstChild:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.url.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(route.snapshot.firstChild.data);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want monitoring and onboarding components to be the children of the main component (appears from your question) you may have to do it this way:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, children: [
      {path:'monitoring', component: MonitoringComponent, outlet: 'c'},
      {path:'onboard', component: OnBoardComponent, outlet: 'c'},
    ] },
];
```

then your router outlet looks like this:

```
<router-outlet name="c"></router-outlet>
```

And finally the links should be:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/main', { outlets: { c: ['monitoring'] } }]">
   Monitoring
</a>

<a [routerLink]="['/main', { outlets: { c: ['onboard'] } }]">
   Onboard
</a>
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: They shouldn't be children of Main but rather siblings. I've already figured it out, see my previous answer.